# alter table to add partitions and subpartitions in mysql

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I have a table that I would like to create partition and subpartitions for it.
I used the alter table statement but I am unable to create subpartitions even by using two alter table statements.
I am only able to create a partition but not subpartitions.I need three levels of subpartitions.

When I execute the file,I keep getting the error:
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that     corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax

But when I remove the statement to create subpartition,I am able to successfully execute the file and create a partition.

Please suggest methods by which I can alter the table to create a partition and three levels of subpartitions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can only create one level of subpartitions (if "level" means that you want to divide each subpartition again into subpartitions, and these again into subpartitions). The correct syntax can be found [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-subpartitions.html). If your code raises an error, it would be a good idea to add your code to the question, as you can do more things wrong than we can list. Also: subpartions are rarely useful (partitions on its own are rarely useful already - they might not do what you think they do), so you might reconsider the *"i need"* statement.

Comment: @Solarflare-Thanks!!Why cannot we divide a subpartition further?

Comment: The simple answer is: because the developers didn't implement it. They probably decided that this feature is not required, or, less likely, did not have the time yet to implement it. If you have compelling reasons that it is needed, feel free to add a feature request (or, since it's open source, implement it yourself). But I would still urge you to reevaluate if you really need sub-sub-subpartitions, as partitions probably work differently than you think they do (they are not a tool to speed up queries, they are mainly a tool for some maintainance tasks or problems).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I question whether `PARTITIONing` is useful at all.  What is your application like?

Second, I have never found a use for `SUBPARTITION`, so I question whether sub-sub-partitioning is of any us either.

I have only found two cases where `PARTITIONing` speeds up `SELECT`.  I can mention about 3 cases where admin stuff is helped by `PARTITIONing`.  [*More discussion*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint).

Please explain your purpose for partitioning.